# Grant permission to output redirection with sudo in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I try to put value "1" into some virtual file of `/proc`, and I get "permission denied" despite using `sudo`:

```
name@comp-name:/etc/dhcp$ sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
bash: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward: Permission denied
```

I guess that `echo` command runs with root permissions, but redirection (`>`) maybe runs without? Can I run both of them with root permissions?

Comment: have you tried using sysctl to write the values in these /proc files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, `sudo` will only apply to `echo`, as you said.

Instead, you could run an elevated shell like this:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'
```

Or even shorter:

```
sudo -s 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'
```

Answer (score 0):

the recommended way to do that is piping to the program `tee`

`echo 1 | tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the redirection is done by your shell, not `sudo`. Ordinarily the program you  run gets `exec()`ed after the redirection. Since you don't have permissions to write to the file, the redirection fails. As mentioned above, the recommended way is to use `tee`, as in

```
echo stuff | sudo tee /some/file/path
```